# Writing callable for method_decorator in DetailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have got a PrintDetailView which I would like to be accessible *only* to either the owner of the print, or to anyone, if the print has its to_publish attribute set to True.

In order to do this, I am trying to use a `permission_required()` method decorator, that accepts a callable from the Print model:

```
class PrintDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'prints/detail.html'
    queryset = Print.objects.all()

    @method_decorator(permission_required('prints.user_is_owner_or_public'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):    
        return super(PrintDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the `user_is_owner_or_public()` method from the Print model:

```
def user_is_owner_or_public(self, user):
        """Checks whether the print is a public print, or
        whether the current user is the owner
        """
        if self.user is user or self.to_publish:
            return True
```

Now, when I test this on a print detail page whose to_publish attribute is set to True, I still see the login screen, so I know that the permission_required() function is being called; however, it's clearly not calling the user_is_owner_or_public() method.

Can anyone give me an understanding of how I might make this work?

TIA, Andy

Comment: Did you add the the permission to the `Meta` class of `PrintDetailView`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not at all what `permission_required` does - `permission_required` is part of the Django permissions system, and will cause Django to check the permissions database table for an appropriately named permission object for the logged in user (either directly granted or granted through a group).  What you're trying to do is outside the scope of decorators around `dispatch` - if nothing else, your print instance isn't loaded until later in the view, so it won't be able to check `to_publish`.

The simplest way I would handle this is to define the `get_queryset` method on the view:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class PrintDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'prints/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Print.objects.filter(Q(user=self.request.user) | Q(to_publish=True))
```

That'll throw a 404 for any print that the user shouldn't be able to see.  If you'd rather redirect to a login page, you'll have to override the `get` method:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class PrintDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'prints/detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not(self.object.to_publish or self.object.user == request.user):
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL) # or a login viewname
        else:
            context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

As a side note, you can use the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator to add restrictions on the dispatch method if they can be determined just from the user object.  That won't help here, but if your test required only the user and not a print instance it would.

Comment: thanks very much for explaining the difference. Good answer, well written.